# Creating a Global Parameter for Modules

Tags: module-display, module-params, template-override

Is it possible to create a Global Configuration option for all the modules? So for example, Every Module has a Title field, If i wanted to add a "Module Tag Line" field to every module?

In reality what i really want is for every module in position "side-bar" to have a Tag Line Field.

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: Please excuse me for asking what might be a stupid question as I'm very tired but could you define exactly what you mean by tag line?

Comment: an additional title field to display underneath the module title. Sorry I may also just be using the wrong wrong word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with modules.php and modChrome:

1. Go to your Module and set a title like this: First Title||Underline Title
2. Then open this file joomlaroot/templates/youtemplate/html/modules.php
3. Between the modChrome_xxxx function, put this code:

`$moduleTitle = explode("||", $module->title);
echo "<h3>".$moduleTitle[0]."</h3>";
if(!empty($moduleTitle[1])){echo "<h5>".$moduleTitle[1]."</h5>";}`

**or**

check this tiny plugin for additional Module Parameters for Joomla:
https://github.com/Nuebel/nnbootstrapparams ! It's for Bootstrap 3 settings, but with little changes, you can use this for your additional modul parameters.

Comment: Ah thank you, I will try the plugin.. Try and keep it clean as possible.. Will let you know...

Comment: You can't use this plugin out of the box for your problem. It's only an example...

Comment: I just altered it a bit and it works 100% THANKS!... Never thought of using a plugin.. uhm...